# HtmlUnit onclick execution download file

Tags: java, htmlunit

So here's the deal:
I am accessing some webpage(using HtmlUnit) on which there's a button. I programatically click that button(big thanks to Mads Hansen)

```
List l = page.getByXPath( "//input[@type='submit' and @value='Save as XML']" );
((HtmlSubmitInput)l.get(0)).click();
```

The button has an onclick event, following:

```
onclick="document.forms[0].action=&quot;calcSaveXML_BG#POS&quot;;document.forms[0].submit()"
```

When I click that button normally through the browser, I am given the chance to save a xml file on my hard drive.
The thing is, I want to be able to get that xml file programatically. Can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I figured that out. In case someone's interested:

```
List l = page.getByXPath( "//input[@type='submit' and @value='Save as XML']" );
XmlPage result = ((HtmlSubmitInput)l.get(0)).click();
String xml = result.getContent();

try
{
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = db.parse( new java.io.ByteArrayInputStream( xml.getBytes( "UTF-8" ) ) );
    doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
    //actual work going here
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```